# I have to show one of nullity $A$ or nullity (I-A) is at least $n/2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $D$ be a division ring and $n \geq 3$. Suppose that $A,B \in M_n(D)$ are two non-zero idempotent matrices.I have $A(I-A)=(I-A)A=0$. I have to show one of nullity $A$ or nullity (I-A) is at least $n/2$.

Comment: So $B$ has nothing to do with anything? Or is there a typo?

Comment: text is: I have $A(I-A)=(I-A)A=0$ . I have to show one of nullity $A$ or nullity $(I-A)$ is at least $n/2$ . then I have to show $(I-A)$ is idempotent. similarly for $B$ , I have to show.

Answer (score 0):

I'll consider elements in $D^n$ as column vectors. We can define the linear maps $f\colon D^n\to D^n$ by $f(x)=Ax$ and $g\colon D^n\to D^n$ by $g(x)=(I-A)x$.

Now let's see that $D^n=\ker f \oplus \ker g$.

Let $x\in\ker f\cap\ker g$; then $Ax=0$ and $(I-A)x=0$, meaning $Ix=0$. Thus $\ker f\cap\ker g=\{0\}$.

Let $x\in D^n$; then $x=(I-A)x+Ax$; since $A((I-A)x)=A(I-A)x=0$ and similarly $(I-A)(Ax)=0$, we have that $\ker f+\ker g=D^n$.

The nullities of $A$ and $I-A$ are precisely the dimensions of $\ker f$ and $\ker g$ respectively.

Now, if both nullities were less than $n/2$, …